# Copy selected files if they are updated and folder structure

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to write a python program, but am unsure where to start.

The requirement is to Write a code that copies selected files and selected folders (along with all subfolders and files) only if the source file is newer than the target file.

For first time all the files will be copied from the above structure to the destination path.

For subsequent runs, only the updated files will be copied + any new files added to the copy list.

The data in the scenario would be something like the below

```
/mnt/datalake/Folder1/file1.csv
/mnt/datalake/Folder1/file2.csv -- Copy this file
/mnt/datalake/Folder1/file3.csv -- Copy this file
/mnt/datalake/Folder1/file4.csv

-- Copy this whole folder
/mnt/datalake/Folder2/Folder3/file5.csv
/mnt/datalake/Folder2/Folder3/file6.png
/mnt/datalake/Folder2/Folder3/file7.jpg

/mnt/datalake/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/file8.xls
/mnt/datalake/Folder4/Folder5/Folder7/file9.csv --Copy Folder7 only alongwith all its subfolders and files
```

The structure of the folders need to remain the same, So in case of copying Folder7 only, the full structure would be created but with data in Folder7 only.
like this:

```
# Destination
/dst/Folder4/Folder5/Folder7/file9.csv
```

The above example files needs to be copied to another datalake storage.
I have tried using the below code.

```
src_folder_list = ['Folder1','Folder2']
src_base_path = 'mnt/datalake/Folderbasepath'
 for foldr in src_folderlist:
  source_path = os.path.join(src_base_path,foldr)
# source directory
  src = '/dbfs' + source_path
# destination directory
  dst = '/dbfs' + tgt_base_path

  if os.path.exists(dst):
      shutil.rmtree(dst)
      shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

This code might not be correct altogether, as it removes the folder structure for the subsequent copy action so only the last folder is retained.

I cannot figure out how to copy files / folders for (updated files only).
Any thoughts / ideas please.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - Solved this myself. Here is the code if anyone else is in a similar situation. The below code, will take folder names / filenames and will copy the hierarchical folder structure and also if only one file is to be copied that will do the job.

You need to create a list with all Folder names and the FileName with Folder structure and it will do the rest of the job.

Also it will check if the file is updated at source, and will copy only if there is a difference.

```
import os
dirlist = ['Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/file.zip','FOLDER5','Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder6'] # List all files / Folders that need to be copied.
base_dir = '/base/path/toSource/'  # Base Path for Source files
dest_root = '/base/path/to/destination/' # Base Path for Destination files
for rootdir in dirlist:
  root = os.path.join(base_dir,rootdir)
  if not os.path.isfile(root):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
      for file in files:
        srcfile = os.path.join(subdir,file)
        des_path = os.path.join(dest_root,subdir[19:],file)
        des_folder = os.path.join(dest_root,subdir[19:])
        print(f'{des_path}')
        if not os.path.exists(des_path):
          print(f'This path is missing Creating Now: {des_path}')
          os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(des_path),exist_ok = True)
          shutil.copy(srcfile,des_path)
        elif (os.path.exists(des_path)): # Check if the file exists - Only copy if the soruce file is updated.
          # If needed version history of the updated file can be recorded here
          if os.stat(srcfile).st_mtime - os.stat(des_path).st_mtime > 1:
            record_version(srcfile,des_path)
            print(f'copying Updated file ... {srcfile}')
            shutil.copy(srcfile,des_path)
          else:
            print(f'Skipping file.. {srcfile}')
  else:
      fpath = os.path.join(dest_root,os.path.dirname(root)[19:],os.path.basename(root))
      if os.path.exists(fpath): # Check if the file exists - Only copy if the soruce file is updated.
        # If needed version history of the updated file can be recorded here
        if os.stat(root).st_mtime - os.stat(fpath).st_mtime > 1:
          record_version(root,fpath)
            print(f'copying Updated file ... {root}')
            shutil.copy(root,fpath)
      else:
        print('Copying new file(s)')
        shutil.copy(root,fpath)
```

Comment: You've missed the method record_version